# What is the best way to ask for level of support for a new laptop model?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions

I am in the market for a new laptop and I would like to ask for the level of support for Ubuntu on recently released laptop models. I would like to be able to ask the askubuntu community if a given laptop model is going to be well supported, but I am not sure if this is a good kind of question for askubuntu. See an example template question below:

```
Are the new VAIO Z Series laptops well supported under Ubuntu 12.04?

VAIO Z Series:
3rd generation Intel® Core™ i7 quad-core processors
3rd generation SSD RAID
Power Media Dock adds optical drive and advanced graphics
```

What is the best way to ask for level of support for a new laptop model?

Answer (score 3):

Asking for shopping recommendations is [off-topic on any Stack Exchange site](https://askubuntu.com/faq) the questions themeselves are too narrow-scoped to be of any real value to anyone else. Shopping recommendations are also so subjective that it's truly difficult to provide any form of an objective answer.

In lieu of this we have a canonical question about "[Which computers are guaranteed to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131/which-computers-are-guaranteed-to-work)" which links to the officially supported hardware page as it's answer.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's my guess that any question of that flavor will be directed to [the certified hardware](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/) page.  I had a similar question about wireless card feature sets, but it wasn't "will this one work".  It was "I'm trying to build a list of wireless cards with feature X".  If you want to see that question it's [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139123/what-purchasable-wireless-cards-support-master-mode-hostapd).

I see a distinction in the two types of question, but others may disagree.

Comment: I've heard about the certified hardware page. Thanks.